# Store SNS share value via function.php

Tags: facebook, post-meta, social-sharing

I am trying to store SNS share value + comment count on my postmeta, DB.
I put code below to accomplish this task,

```
function get_sns_share($post_ID=0) { 
    $url1=get_permalink($post->ID);
    $src = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $url1));
    $share_count = $src->shares; // facebook commnet + comment like + share + like
    $my_var = get_comments_number( $post_id ); // comment count
    $social_score = $share_count + $my_var + $tweet; // social score sum
        if ($social_score > 999) $social_socre = 999;

    return $social_score;

update_post_meta($post_id, '_social_score', $social_score);
}
```

The problem is this code certainly do works every field other than update_post_meta. It seems it does not add add post meta field to my database, thus I cannot get any value from there. Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a function or method, the `return` statement immediately stops the execution of the earlier.

Hence the last line never gets interpreted.

Switch the order of this:

```
return $social_score; 
update_post_meta($post_id, '_social_score', $social_score);
```

to this:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, '_social_score', $social_score);
return $social_score;
```

**Update:**

You are using three different variables for the post id, namely: `$post_ID`, `$post_id` and `$post->ID`. You should use the function argument: `$post_ID`.

Comment: Within a function or method, the `return` statement immediately stops the execution of the earlier.

Comment: Thanks, birgire and Johannes. I tried the code below, but it still does not add or update the post_meta in the DB. I guess I am missing something, but I am not sure what that would be. :(

Comment: You can try the updated the answer.